# Counting how many platters can be made with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

> **A person always prefers to eat 'parantha' and 'vegetable dish' in his meal. How many ways can he make his platter in a marriage party,
>   if there are three types of paranthas, 4 types of vegetable dish,
>   three types of salads and two types of sauces?**

1. 3360
2. 4096
3. 3000
4. None of these

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the restrictions are.  Will he always eat exactly one type of parantha?  Will he possibly eat multiple types of parantha simultaneously?  Possibly no types of parantha?  Will he always eat exactly one type of salad?  Possibly multiple types of salad?  Possibly no salads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

In how many ways can he get at least one of the paranthas, at least one of the vegetable dishes, and zero or more of the other 5 dishes?